# Flask/Python application: OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

**app.py**

```
#basic flask skeleton
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from JobApplicationTracker.models import User


#Flask application instance named app - __name__ represents the current module
app = Flask(__name__)

#configure SQLite db URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///job-application-tracker.db'

#disable track mods
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#route for the root url ("/"). root url is visited - func below is executed
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        #new user object
        new_user = User(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('success'))

    return render_template('registration.html')

@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return render_template('success.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**models.py**

```
#Flask-SQLAlchemy: an extension for integrating SQLAlchemy with Flask for database management.
#werkzeug.security is imported to use functions for password hashing and verification.
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


#SQLAlchemy instance - represents application's database connection
db = SQLAlchemy()

#user class inherits from db.Model (base class provided by flask)
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    #identifier for each user in database
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 

    #each username/email in the db must be unique and cannot be empty
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    #stores the hashed version of the user's password
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self,username,email,password): #initalize/constructor
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        #hashes and sets the user's password
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        #verifies a password during l
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
aiofiles==22.1.0
aiosqlite==0.18.0
alembic==1.12.0
anyio==3.6.2
appnope==0.1.3
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.2.3
asttokens==2.2.1
attrs==22.2.0
Babel==2.12.1
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.0
bleach==6.0.0
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.7
comm==0.1.3
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
executing==1.2.0
fastjsonschema==2.16.3
Flask==2.3.3
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-Migrate==4.0.4
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.5
Flask-WTF==1.1.1
fqdn==1.5.1
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.22.0
ipython==8.11.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isoduration==20.11.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
json5==0.9.11
jsonpointer==2.3
jsonschema==4.17.3
jupyter-events==0.6.3
jupyter-ydoc==0.2.3
jupyter_client==8.1.0
jupyter_core==5.3.0
jupyter_server==2.5.0
jupyter_server_fileid==0.8.0
jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4
jupyter_server_ydoc==0.8.0
jupyterlab==3.6.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab_server==2.21.0
Mako==1.2.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mistune==2.0.5
nbclassic==0.5.3
nbclient==0.7.2
nbconvert==7.2.10
nbformat==5.8.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
notebook==6.5.3
notebook_shim==0.2.2
packaging==23.0
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
platformdirs==3.2.0
prometheus-client==0.16.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
psutil==5.9.4
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.14.0
pyrsistent==0.19.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-json-logger==2.0.7
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==25.0.2
requests==2.28.2
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.4
SQLAlchemy==2.0.20
stack-data==0.6.2
terminado==0.17.1
tinycss2==1.2.1
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.9.0
typing_extensions==4.7.1
uri-template==1.2.0
urllib3==1.26.15
wcwidth==0.2.6
webcolors==1.13
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.5.1
Werkzeug==2.3.7
WTForms==3.0.1
y-py==0.5.9
ypy-websocket==0.8.2
```

I've also attached screenshots of the file structure and the error I'm getting.
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bElVw.png)
[Error message in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKuH8.png)

I am in the early steps of creating an application using Python3 and Flask. I'm using SQLite for my database, and I am running into an error when trying to add a user to the database. The '/' route loads fine, and I can go to the `'/register'` route with no issues, but I get an error when I hit the actual register button after entering username, email, and password. I've browsed similar posts, but they haven't helped. Many of my attempts have focused around using db.create_all() (which I got from other posts on here), but I have also seen conflicting resources that say `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` is equivalent to doing just that. Additionally, I have also tried doing the following 3 commands: `flask db init`, `flask db migrate`, and `flask db upgrade`, neither of which seemed to work. At this point I'm a bit lost on what to do and how to proceed with resolving this error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` command creates your database connection instance, but does not create the tables.  There are many ways to create those tables.  Running `db.create_all()` is one of those ways.

Comment: @Malcolm Where would the db.create_all() command go? I tried it in both app.py and models.py

Comment: I believe you want it in app.py before your app.run.  I am a bit fuzzy on that because I have generally used Alembic to manage my database versioning.

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: @Alex
I get an error when adding that to the if statement. First, I add ', db' to the models import in app.py, then I add the db.create_all() to the if statement. I get the following: 

'RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
... To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.'

I then modify the if statement like this:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)

However, the same issue of 'no such table: user' persists

Comment: Ah.  I think I see the problem.  You are overriding the `User.__init__` method without calling `super().__init__()`, so I suspect your User class isn't getting setup correctly as a db.Model class and so is not recognized as a Model requiring a table creation.  Typically when extending db.Model, I don't think you want to override `__init__`.

Comment: Check out https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/models/

Comment: @Malcolm I've read over the link, but I'm not quite sure what changes to make to my code. I've added `with app.app_context(): db.create_all` at the end of models.py, but I'm not sure how to define `app`. I also tried changing the `__init__` method in the `User` class to `initialize` (renamed it), as you said it is getting overridden. Should I just try and re-write models.py in accordance to what the link is saying?

Answer (score 0):

With models.py file as above, but with the `__init__` method renamed, try the following for app.py

```
#basic flask skeleton
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from JobApplicationTracker.models import User, db  # use the db from your models.py file

#Flask application instance named app - __name__ represents the current module
app = Flask(__name__)

#configure SQLite db URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///job-application-tracker.db'

#disable track mods
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db.init_app(app)  # use init_app instead of the SQLAlchemy contsructor

#route for the root url ("/"). root url is visited - func below is executed
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        #new user object
        new_user = User(username=username, email=email)
        new_user.set_password(password)  # set password after constructor

        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('success'))

    return render_template('registration.html')

@app.route('/success')
def success():
    return render_template('success.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():  # create the database tables
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

That at least should get your application to run and create the database tables, and now handle the password_hash saving correctly.

Changes from your original:

- in app.py

  - import db object from your models.py file
  - call db.init_app(app) rather than creating a new db with the SQLAlchemy contructor
  - call the set_password method on new_user explicitly
  - run `db.create_all()` inside a `with app.app_context()` block

    - for production you will probably want to move this to a separate script for creating the database.  You don't need to run it every time you start the server.
- in models.py

  - rename or remove the `__init__` method.

Comment: I have updated the answer to properly handle the hashed password and added a summary of the changes at the end.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I can now see the 'Success' page after registering a user. I appreciate your detailed response. If you don't mind me asking, how did you determine that it was the __init__ method in models.py that was causing the error?

Comment: In my experience and in all the examples I can find of having model classes extend `db.Model`, no `__init__` method is implemented by the model class.  The Flask examples where the model classes implement an `__init__` method are ones that extend the `declarative_base()` generated class directly.  I suspect the db.Model class (which does extend a declarative_base class) must implement its own `__init__` method and overriding it without calling super().__init__() most certainly fails to set things that `db.create_all()` needs to identify the class as requiring a database table.